# where to set "break" in nested loop

Tags: python, loops, nested, break

I am learning about nested loops and I have come across the use of break. I don't quite understand where to place break in the nested loop to get the correct output.
I have tried three different codes, and don't understand them fully.

code 1: Interruption of the loop after the first round of j (j=0), but continuation of the nested loop itself - this code is understandable for me and is used as comparison for the next codes.

```
for i in range(6):                 
    print('hello')
    if i<=3:                        
        for j in range(3):
            print('hi')             
            break                   
        print('bye')
```

code 2: interrupts the entire nested loop after the first round (i=0, j=0,1,2), why doesn't it just interrupt j? Compared to code 1, I thought break has moved from the single round of loop j to the whole loop of j. But this does not seem to be the case. And I have read, break interruppts the closest loop, which would be j.

```
for i in range(6):
    print('hello')
    if i<=3:
        for j in range(3):
            print('hi')
        break                       
        print('bye')
```

code 3: And here I moved break even further, but get the same result as code 2.

```
for i in range(6):
    print('hello')
    if i<=3:
        for j in range(3):
            print('hi')
    break                      
    print('bye')
```

Comment: `break` _breaks out of the innermost enclosing `for` or `while` loop_ [*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). In the first example, that's `for j in range(3):` and in the last 2 examples it's `for i in range(6):`

Comment: What is the desired output you are trying to get?

Comment: @001 I have no desired output, I just wanted to understand, what happens if I locate break in different places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` breaks out of the *innermost* loop the `break` statement is directly inside of.

```
for i in range(...):
   ...
   break
```

This `break` is inside the `for i` loop, so it'll stop the entire `for i` loop. Any loops that are outside are untouched:

```
for j in ...:
   for i in ...:
      break # Terminate the `for i` loop
   # The `for j` loop continues
```

Placing `break` *next* to another loop affects the loop `break` is *inside of* anyway:

```
for i in ...:
    for j in ...:
        print('Hello')
    break
    # Outside `for j`, but inside `for i`,
    # so only `for i` loop can be affected by this `break`
```

"`break` interrupts the closest loop" means "`break` interrupts the innermost loop".

Placing `break` inside an `if` statement still terminates the loop the `break` is inside of, but only `if` some condition is met:

```
for i in ...:
    for j in ...:
       if i > j: break # Get out of the `for j` loop ONLY IF `i > j`
```

Answer (score 0):

You understand the code flow and output of the first block of code and that is great. If you don't follow the flow in the other blocks, you might be able to use a debugger to execute the code line by line to see how it works.

That aside, let's look at block 2:

```py
for i in range(6):
    print('hello')
    if i<=3:
        for j in range(3):
            print('hi')
        break                       
        print('bye')
```

We would expect this code to `print('hello')` one time as the first time we print is when `i` is `0`. Since 0 is less than or equal to 3, we enter the `if` block and go on to `print('hi')` three times then we hit the `break` statement and that dumps us out of our `for i` loop as `break` works against the loop context we are in, not the one geographically closest to. Note that you never get to `print('bye')` as the `break` dumped us out of the loop.

Now for block 3:

```py
for i in range(6):
    print('hello')
    if i<=3:
        for j in range(3):
            print('hi')
    break                      
    print('bye')
```

We get the same output "hello" and 3 x "hi" but the `break` dump happens at a slightly different point in time. Note we still never hit `print('bye')`.

In this 3rd block, rather than the `break` being the last thing we do inside our `if` statement, it is now the first thing we do after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement can only be used on loops. Not If statements.

In example 1 your `break` statement is part of your nested `for` loop.

In example 2 and 3 your break statement falls outside of your nested `for` loop and the *only* other loop to attach itself is your first `for` loop.

Once that original loop is broken out of there is nothing else to run and the program ends.